# Python zeromq -- Multiple Publishers To a Single Subscriber?

Tags: python, zeromq

I'd like to write a `python` script (call it **parent**) that does the following:

**(1)** defines a multi-dimensional `numpy` array

**(2)** `forks` 10 different `python` scripts (call them **children**). Each of them must be able to `read` the contents of the `numpy` array from **(1)** at any single point in time (as long as they are alive).

**(3)** each of the **child** scripts will do it's own work (**children** DO NOT share any info with each other)

**(4)** at any point in time, the **parent** script must be able to accept messages from all of its **children**. These messages will be *parsed by the parent* and cause the `numpy` array from **(1)** to change.

---

How do I go about this, when working in `python` in a `Linux` environment? I thought of using `zeroMQ` and have the **parent** be a single *subscriber* while the **children** will all be *publishers*; does it make sense or is there a better way for this?

Also, how do I allow all the **children** to continuously *read* the contents of the `numpy` array that was defined by the **parent** ?

Comment: Have you considered using the PUSH/PULL model, as described in http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Divide-and-Conquer? Only the ventilator and sink are the same process...

Answer (score 19):

The `sub` channel doesn't have to be the one to bind, so you can have the subscriber bind, and each of the children `pub` channels can connect to that and send their messages. In this particular case, I think the `multiprocessing` module is a better fit, but I thought it bore mentioning:

```
import zmq
import threading

# So that you can copy-and-paste this into an interactive session, I'm
# using threading, but obviously that's not what you'd use

# I'm the subscriber that multiple clients are writing to
def parent():
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'Child:')
    # Even though I'm the subscriber, I'm allowed to get this party 
    # started with `bind`
    socket.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5000')

    # I expect 50 messages
    for i in range(50):
        print 'Parent received: %s' % socket.recv()

# I'm a child publisher
def child(number):
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    # And even though I'm the publisher, I can do the connecting rather
    # than the binding
    socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5000')

    for data in range(5):
        socket.send('Child: %i %i' % (number, data))
    socket.close()

threads = [threading.Thread(target=parent)] + [threading.Thread(target=child, args=(i,)) for i in range(10)]
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

In particular, the [Core Messaging Patterns](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Core-Messaging-Patterns) part of the documentation discusses the fact that for the patterns, either side can bind (and the other connect).

Comment: I think you mean to say... "The PUB channel doesn't have to be the one to bind"

Comment: I copied this into a py script and ran it.  It just hangs on the recv command and never prints anything.

Comment: Its probably because you didn't wait for the connect to finish. I've added time.sleep(0.1) after the connect and it worked.

Comment: Working for me on a subnet between nodes

Comment: Note that you probably wont experience a great performance boost, as the GIL reduces the chances that your threads really run in parallel. As mentioned above you can avoid that by using the `multiprocessing` module. See e.g. https://emptysqua.re/blog/grok-the-gil-fast-thread-safe-python/ for a good explanation of the GIL.

Answer (score 4):

I think it makes more sense to use PUSH/PULL sockets, as you have a standard [Ventilator - Workers - Sink](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Divide-and-Conquer) scenario, except that the Ventilator and the Sink are the same process.

Also, consider using the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module instead of ZeroMQ. It will probably be a bit easier.

Comment: tsg, thank you for your reply. `multiprocessing` is good -- but can I use it to share a `numpy` array? my shared object (ideally, `numpy` array) will have a matrix of 20,000,000 x 5 items. A regular `list` will be a huge memory waste.

Comment: also, how do I share the **parent** `numpy` array for READING among all **children**?

Comment: The first link is dead

Answer (score -2):

In ZeroMQ there can only be one publisher per port. The only (ugly) workaround is to start each child PUB socket on a different port and have the parent listen on all those ports.

but the pipeline pattern describe on 0MQ, user guide is a much better way to do this.

Comment: This is not quite accurate.  You can only *bind* one socket to a port, but in this scenario, there is no reason not to bind with the SUB, and connect all the PUBs to that one port.  ZeroMQ doesn't care at all about bind/connect directions.